# Running chrome in Backtrack Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, sudo, root, backtrack

I am using the Backtrack 5 linux distribution, and i wanted to install chrome, but it wont run as root for default.

I know that using `--user-data-dir` will let me run it as root.

**But is there a safer way to use chrome on this linux distribution without having to run it as root?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

default user in Backtrack is root, but you can try adduser

`# type adduser`

```
adduser is /usr/sbin/adduser
```

then add an unprivileged user, give him groups rights

`# adduser <name>`
`# passwd <name>`

enter the password 2 times, and logout/reboot.

login as the unprivileged user should work.

Answer (score 2):

1) create normal user

```
$ sudo useradd knoim
$ sudo passwd knoim
```

2) login as normal user

```
$ su knoim
<knoims password>
```

3) run firefox
$
`$ firefox` or spawn a process  `$ firefox &`

PS: this solution should work for most linux distro including backtrack. if you have already root privileges ( you have already said it but i meant to write general solution) you do not need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

Backtrack forum has this already as:

HowTo Create an Unprivileged (non root) User in BackTrack
http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=1741